# Minimum eligibility to become a theory

Tags: axioms

Is there any mathematical theory without any axioms?

Theories such as [set theory](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Set_Theory/Axioms), [number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) etc., all has axioms in it.

I have confusion between mathematical theory and the word theory in usage such as [Automata theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/104433/what-are-the-axioms-of-automata-theory).

Comment: You have not to conflate "formalized theory" with "theory" meaning "the study of ...". [Automata theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory) is the study of the mathematical properties of abstract machines or *automata*, like linear algebra is the study of the math properties of *matrices*.

Comment: If you consider instead a formal system for some branch of mathematics, based on e.g. [first order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Syntax), obviously we need some (at least one) mateìhematical axioms. Without them, what we have is simply the underlying logic, e.g. predicate calculus with equality.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If both are different, is there any reason for making such nomenclature?

Comment: [Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory) is a term with a very broad meaning, used in many contexts.

Comment: Among the many usage of "theory", we can find [Axiomatic system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiomatic_system) : "any set of axioms from which some or all axioms can be used in conjunction to logically derive theorems. A *theory* consists of an axiomatic system and all its derived theorems. " This is quite different from e.g. the [Theory of art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_art).